# Can I get a Star at attractions other than the Team Attractions?

Tags: nintendo-land

I've now earned a star at all three Team Attractions (Zelda, Metroid, Pikmin) for being a "star player" i.e. completing all the main levels. I've unlocked everything (I think) in the competitive attractions but have no earned stars in them, or any of the single player attractions.

Are there stars to earn in every attraction, just the Team attractions or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that yes, each Attraction can earn a star, as explained in this video:

Basically the requirements are:

Team Attractions

- Complete all "standard" levels for the Attraction (competitive modes and Extra levels don't count)

Competitive Attractions

- Play each competitive attraction 30 times (win or lose)

Single Player Attractions

- Complete each Attractions "main game", since they're all arcade style games, this pretty much just requires you to play until the game ends. Some games have a second course, which doesn't count for the star. Unlocking the second course is usually enough to unlock the star, as well.

As a bonus, when you've earned all stars, you can see the credits (yay) and play a star shooting minigame (less sarcastic yay).